# How to rewrite prestashop friendly urls? (not the htaccess file but url for each product)

Tags: url, prestashop

For some reason in my shop some of the friendly urls are mixed up. For example I have a product with name "White wine glass 280 ml" and the friendly url is "250-red-wine-glass-300-ml.html". If I go to product edit page and select SEO and click generate URL than the url is corect and all is fine but I don't want to do that for each product in shop. 
How can I do that for all the products at once?

I tried finding where are the urls stored in db to delete them and hope presta would autognerate them but I couldn't find where they are saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do an override of Dispatcher.php class or use hookModulesRoutes in a Module.

Just create overrides/classes/Dispatcher.php and modify original methods/variable to get what you want to achieve here. You will have to modify how pages are grabed by PHP/Prestashop by altering the script getting the (for exemple) product ID and make a search inside your products url_rewrite to get the good one.

Honestly this is a tought job and lots of modules available are doing it very well, you should have a look as some are very cheap (less than 20$).